# Excel VBA calls Bloomberg terminal and enters a query, how do I enter the Yellow Key/ Market Sector of a security correctly in my code?

Tags: excel, api, vba, bloomberg

Hi I'm doing something in Excel vba that when I click the button that runs the macro it enters a query in Bloomberg and brings me to a security and a function that views it.

```
Blp = DDEInitiate("Winblp", "bbk")
Call DDEExecute(Blp, "<Blp-1>" & "APPL US Equity" & " DES<GO>")
Call DDETerminate(ch)
```

Now the problem is that this query goes into Bloomberg it never detects it as a valid security. I think this is definitely a yellow button issue, i.e. if you just type APPL US Equity into Bloomberg as opposed to APPL US [Equity] with yellow button it just wont work.

Is there a special object or string that I need to enter to have this query go in correctly? I've tried to search Google but can't find anything.

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use the VBA API instead of sending DDE queries? In particular you can use the `CIE_DES` field to get the company description. Or you could paste a `=BDP("AAPL US Equity","CIE_DES")` in a cell...

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. This is not the function I'm going for. I have designed a huge application that pulls a few thousand data using BDP(). I want to give user the option to take a ticker and interact with it in Bloomberg. Just a shortcut to Bloomberg without having to switch screen and type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Equity` is a reserved keyword like `Go`, you can access it with:

```
Blp = DDEInitiate("Winblp", "bbk")
Call DDEExecute(Blp, "<Blp-1>" & "AAPL US <EQUITY>" & " DES<GO>")
Call DDETerminate(Blp)
```

ps: two typos in your code:

- APPL => AAPL (I suppose)
- `DDETerminate(ch)` => `DDETerminate(Blp)`.

Comment: APPL was just a filler. But thanks that's exactly what I needed!